# Hide sidebar control based on the logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have   a master page whereby have got controls for User and staff.I need to hide the controls for  certain specific users such that they can only see a report on a radgrid.The sidebar got links where one can add students  and navigate to other links  too.Is their a way i can hide the sidebar for  specific users?

Answer (score 0):

Use Asp.net `LongIn View` , Here is an example ,

```
<asp:LoginView runat="Server" id="LoginView1">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        The Anonymous Template is displayed for anonymous users.
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        The Logged In Template is displayed for users logged in.
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
            <ContentTemplate>
                This Role Groups Template is displayed for admins.
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

In my example , I add "Admin" to `Role Group`.
You should add your users into specific `Row Group` and you can dynamically show and hide Contents based on logged-in user !